# Problem compiling gcc 4.4.0 on OpenSolaris 2009.6

Tags: gcc, solaris, opensolaris

I am attempting to compile gcc 4.4.0 on opensolaris 2009.6

Currently in the box (which is a AMD 64bit machine), I have the gcc 3.4.6 installed.

I unpacked the gcc 4.4.0 tarball.

I set the following env variables:

```
export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc
```

Then I ran "configure && make" and this is the error message that I got:

```
checking for i386-pc-solaris2.11-gcc... /export/home/me/wd/gcc/gcc-4.4.0/host-i386-pc-solaris2.11/gcc/xgcc -B/export/home/me/wd/gcc/gcc-4.4.0/host-i386-pc-solaris2.11/gcc/ -B/usr/local/i386-pc-solaris2.11/bin/ -B/usr/local/i386-pc-solaris2.11/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/i386-pc-solaris2.11/include -isystem /usr/local/i386-pc-solaris2.11/sys-include  -m64
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/export/home/me/wd/gcc/gcc-4.4.0/i386-pc-solaris2.11/amd64/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Anyone has any suggestion as to how to work around this error message?

/Edit:
Content of the config.log is posted here: [link text](http://pastebin.com/m17c28c98)

Comment: can you post the part from config.log on the error?

Comment: I have posted the content here: http://pastebin.com/m17c28c98

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the GCC build is bootstrapped, i.e. first it uses the system compiler to build GCC C compiler, and then it uses the freshly built compiler to recompile GCC once again (and then even once more time again). The configure line shows that it is not the system compiler but the already-built GCC compiler which is used for configure test there.

Since it fails, the problem is that the freshly-built GCC is somehow "stillborn" here. If config.log will not help you, I'd suggest to ask at gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org.

EDIT: Ah-ha, I think it is the assembler. You are using GNU assembler, but the unsupported options look like they were meant for Sun assembler. This should be solved by adding `--with-gnu-as` configure option (and then possibly having to specify its path explicitly with `--with-as=/usr/gnu/bin/as`)

You can also take a look at [Solaris-specific GCC build instructions](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html#ix86-x-solaris210).

Comment: When i go through the config.log, I pick up this line:

/usr/gnu/bin/as: unrecognized option `-xarch=generic64'

Don't know if it is related...

Comment: I think Kastaurya is spot on. Depending on your configuration, you may also want to check the --with-gnu-ld option.

Answer (score 1):

There's a readily available build for gcc4, which you can try updating. Its current version is 4.3.3. To get started, install `pkg-get` from OpenCSW and check out the build from the subversion repository:

```
svn co https://gar.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/gar/csw/mgar/pkg/gcc4/trunk/ gcc4
cd gcc4
gmake package
```