# Error 1 & 2 when compiling GCC 4.4.2 on OpenSolaris 2009.06

Tags: gcc, compilation, opensolaris

**My problem:**

I've been trying to compile, build, and install GCC 4.4.2 in my installation of OpenSolaris 2009.06 on my VirtualBox 3 i386 machine. But I keep getting this same error when running make:

```
> checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for i386-pc-solaris2.11-gcc... /src/gcc-4.4.2/host-i386-pc-solaris2.11/gcc/xgcc -B/src/gcc-4.4.2/host-i386-pc-solaris2.11/gcc/ -B/usr/gnu/i386-pc-solaris2.11/bin/ -B/usr/gnu/i386-pc-solaris2.11/lib/ -isystem /usr/gnu/i386-pc-solaris2.11/include -isystem /usr/gnu/i386-pc-solaris2.11/sys-include
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/src/gcc-4.4.2/i386-pc-solaris2.11/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/src/gcc-4.4.2'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/src/gcc-4.4.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Attempted solutions:**

1. I tried the answer to this question:
   [Problem compiling gcc 4.4.0 on OpenSolaris 2009.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990752/problem-compiling-gcc-4-4-0-on-opensolaris-2009-6) i.e.

   > ./configure --prefix=/usr/gnu --with-gmp=/usr/gnu --with-mpfr=/usr/gnu --with-as=/usr/sfw/bin/gas --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld
2. I tried GNU GCC's platform specific solution:
   [GNU Solaris specific build instructions](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html#ix86-x-solaris210)
   i.e.

   > ./configure --prefix=/usr/gnu --with-gmp=/usr/gnu --with-mpfr=/usr/gnu --with-as=/usr/sfw/bin/gas --with-gnu-as --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --without-gnu-ld --enable-shared

**I am still getting the same errors despite running ./configure with the two solutions above**

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: It says "see config.log for more details" - is there anything helpful in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Can you compile programs with the existing GCC?

  > If not, you need to resolve that.
  >
  > If you can, then you need to look at that monstrous 7-argument command (the one where it says 'checking for i386-pc-solaris2.11-gcc' - why those 7 arguments?).
- Are you running 'make bootstrap'?

  > If not, what happens when you do?
  >
  > If so, whereabouts in the processing is it?  (Is this stage 1, or stage 2, or what?)
- Are you using the recommended setup, with the source for GCC in, say, /src/gcc-4.4.2 and the object files in, say, /src/gcc-4.4.2-obj?

  > If not, do so.  Use: `cd /src/gcc-4.4.2-obj; ../gcc-4.4.2/configure ...`
- Which shell do you use?

  > On regular Solaris 10 (not OpenSolaris - and SPARC, not Intel), I have to set CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/ksh in the environment to make things compile (by default, it uses /bin/sh, but the /bin/sh on Solaris 10 is Bourne shell and there's a script deep down in the Java section (IIRC) that uses Bash/Korn/POSIX shell notations like `$(cmd ...)`).  However, that normally affects a much later stage in the processing.

However, I have got GCC 4.4.2 on Solaris 10 without problem (using GCC 4.4.1 as the bootstrap compiler).

Comment: I tried doing 'make bootstrap' but I the process went on for a few hours then produced an 'out of memory' Error 2. I tried to restart by first running 'make clean && make distclean' and one of the messages was 'Recursive variable `AR_FOR_TARGET' references itself ..... [clean-stage3-target-libgcc] Error 2'. Any ideas?

Comment: Now after doing "make bootstrap" I get a different error message:
"checking whether the C compiler works... configure: error: in `/src/gcc-4.4.2/i386-pc-solaris2.11/amd64/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage3-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/src/gcc-4.4.2'
make[1]: *** [stage3-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/src/gcc-4.4.2'
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2"

Does anyone know what this means? Thanks!

Comment: Regarding time - it is certainly a fairly long-winded process, but if you run with 'make -j4' (with a number appropriate to the number of cores on your machine), it will certainly take less time if you use a number bigger than one.  You also need copious space - of the order of 2-4 GB.  This usually isn't a problem on modern systems, but be aware of it (I have to make space on my antique SPARC).  The 'recursive variable' is puzzling.

Comment: Regarding your new error, that is odd.  This is the stage 3 compilation - which is an unusual place to get this sort of error.  Stage 1 uses an exiting compiler to compile the new GCC; stage 2 uses the new GCC to compile itself; stage 3 uses the rebuilt stage 2 compiler to rebuild itself, and checks that it gets the same answer.  The final stage builds support libraries and other things that have not previously been built. [...to be continued...]

Comment: [...continued...]  I forget whether the final build phase is formally stage 3 or a separate phase.  So, the Stage 3 clean and configure should be using the new GCC to rebuild itself - but it is unusual for that to be causing trouble.  I'm not sure what could be going wrong.  I presume you are using an AMD64 chip?  And you are not cross-compiling?

Comment: Actually my chip is an Intel Core 2 Duo 2.0 gHz and I am not cross-compiling. Also I just tried the same thing (to be sure) and got the same error.

Comment: By the way, I also tried to do this:
"./configure --prefix=/usr/gnu --program-suffix=-4.4.2 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-libtool-lock --target= --enable-objc-gc --enable-concept-checks --disable-libada --enable-libssp --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran --enable-threads=posix

Comment: --enable-tls=yes --with-system-zlib --without-gnu-ld --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --with-gnu-as --with-as=/usr/sfw/bin/gas --with-gmp-include=/usr/gnu/include/ --with-gmp-lib=/usr/gnu/lib --with-mpfr-include=/usr/gnu/include/ --with-mpfr-lib=/usr/gnu/lib --enable-c99 --enable-nls --enable-wchar_t --enable-libstdcxx-allocator=mt --with-pic"

Comment: I got this above very long set of options by running './gcc -v' and seeing how my existing copy of gcc is compiled.

Comment: If you are not using an AMD64 chip, you need to wonder why the configure is choosing that option. It depends on whether the Core 2 Duo looks enough like AMD64, I suppose - I'm running out of ideas and the relevant experience to help. I've compiled GCC often enough; I built 4.4.2 earlier this week, and removed 4.2.3 version to make space for it (I still have 4.4.1 and 4.3.3 and 3.4.6 lurking around installed). I'm gonna try some 'stuff' - I'll let you know whether I find anything out.

Comment: Not sure how significant it is, but when I build GCC 4.4.2 on MacOS X 10.5.8, it uses x86_64 rather than AMD for the architecture.  Picking one library, it is /usr/gcc/v4.4.2/lib/x86_64/libgomp.1.dylib.  I think you need to look at whether the chosen architecture is correct for your platform.